# Why is the CC-BY license so long?

Tags: licensing, open-source-software, creative-commons

The [CC-BY 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/legalcode) license is 1,958 words.

As I understand it, the [MIT license](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT) is functionally equivalent to CC-BY: it established that you can do *whatever* with the published work, as long as you give credit.

But the MIT license is just 162 words, most of which are in the disclaimer. The [ISC license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISC_license), which should be functionally equivalent to the MIT license, is even shorter: just 111 words.

Why is the CC-BY *so much* longer than the MIT or ISC license, even though it offers the same conditions? Or this question could also be reversed: why are the MIT/ISC licenses so short compared to the CC-BY license?

Comment: In my world, a custom drafted licensing agreement typically runs about 2500 to 9000 words. A 1,958 word licensing agreement is honestly pretty economical. A license of 162 words or less is so short that it terrifies me as a lawyer. I'd feel challenged to identify the parties and put in a signature block with that few words. Hell, it is hard to write a transmittal letter that short. The reverse question that you suggest is more on target.

Answer (score 4):

You have a false premise: "it offers the same conditions", and "MIT license is functionally equivalent to CC-BY". These premises are not true.

CC-BY:

- applies to more than just software; it applies to artistic or literary work, databases, other material
- disclaims endorsement
- explicitly withholds moral rights
- explicitly does not license patent rights (MIT license gives anyone who obtains a copy of the software the right to use it, a patent right)
- prescribes the acceptable forms of attribution

Those are just some of the differences.

Comment: I think a large part of it is just the nature of the licenses. The MIT/ISC licenses were kind of intended to be short, and they kind of offer a lot of protections through omission, or really concise language. CC actually goes to create definitions of every term, address moral rights, sui generis rights, termination, survival clauses... and so on